# How can I copy System Info to clipboard?

Tags: applescript

I am creating a program that copies System Info to the clipboard.  I have tried setting a variable to System Info and copying that variable but it only copies my AppleScript version (2.2.4). Please help! My code is below:

```
set a to system info
set the clipboard to a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to coerce the record to a list...

```
set a to (system info) as list
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set a to a as text
set the clipboard to a
```